# Can I do this sort of thing with java annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a set of methods that I call and a main handler, something like this:

```
public class MyHander
{
    HashMap<String, Method> methodMap = ...;

    static {
        ... fill the methodMap by looking up local methods
        methodMap.put("typeA", findMethod("handleTypeA"));
        .... etc.
    }

    public void handle(MyObject obj) {
        Method handler = methodMap.get(obj.getType());
        handler.invoke(.....);
    }

    private handleTypeA() {
        ....
    }

    private handleTypeB() {
        ....
    }
}
```

So that's generally what I do to call my individual handler methods.  Would I be able to do something similar by annotating the methods handleTypeA(), handleTypeB(), etc and then finding the correct one in my main handle() method?

Comment: So something like `@Handle(TypeA.class)` on `handleTypeA()`?

Comment: This seems more suited to using something like the Strategy Pattern than to annotation processing - at least to me.

Comment: Or perhaps the Visitor pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create an annotation for the handler methods that listed the types they accepted and create a class to process them and return a handler map. This would move the error-prone code in the static initializer into a testable factory class.

```
public class MyHander
{
    HashMap<String, Method> methodMap = HandlerType.buildMap(MyHandler.class);

    public void handle(MyObject obj) {
        Method handler = methodMap.get(obj.getType());
        handler.invoke(.....);
    }

    @HandlerType({"typeA", "typeAprime"})
    private handleTypeA() {
        ....
    }

    @HandlerType({"typeB"})
    private handleTypeB() {
        ....
    }
}
```

`HandlerType.buildMap` would use reflection to process the annotations. You'll need to make sure you can pass an array as the default annotation parameter or do something clever like encode it as a comma-separated string.